# Formula is over 8,192 characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

there is no short version of this, but I'll do my best:
i have a formula that takes input from 4 dropdowns and 3 cells that fill down a column to give an output on each line. the function is primarily CONCATENATE() so it takes a lot of room to combine text and references and SUBSTITUTE()s.

my first idea was to break up the function between multiple cells and make calls to those cells, but since this is designed to fill down columns (like 200lines or more) i would need multiple columns running multiple calculations and my goal is to consolidate. i did try to use the EVALUATE() function as part of a Defined Name, but that also has a size limit (its really short).

my second idea was to break up the function into those many columns, but i want to have a cell that can have data input, but when data is entered on a different sheet it displays that data. (the opposite of displaying blank cell until data is entered).

so, are there any good options for a function that is too long, can't be shortened, and does not use vba? i'd like to have a function that is more 'object oriented' and just reference those cells, but it won't pass my text to another cell as 'function' text only as 'text' text.

best example i can give:

```
A1:IF(A2>2,CONCATENATE(.....))

B1:=IF(B2<9,A1,CONCATENATE(...))
```

(where `B1` will process the text in the cell, not just read the result since `A1` has no `=` )

Comment: Very often, when a formula get ginormous, there's a different way of doing things. It might be better if you could [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55270534/edit) to let us know what you are trying to accomplish with such a formula. Some sample data would also be useful.

Comment: i'm afraid the example would be as long as the problem i'm having, its only 4 nested IF() statements, but each one is to CONCATENATE() a length of data and text, and each one uses multiple SUBSTITUTES() in order to remove incorrect characters from the input. The length is just the sheer volume of text that needs to be put together.

Comment: you don't need Concatenate(). Instead of `Concatenate(A1,"-",B1)` you can use `A1 & "-" & B1` - that will save a few characters.

Comment: CLEAN and TRIM may get rid of some of your characters instead of substitute.  but it would depend on the characters.

Comment: @PaulVOiP you can always throw logic for the concatenation in a function and it will reduce the hell out of your formula but performance may suffer. Also look at TEXTJOIN ... it may help. Depends on how granular your substitute needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break the long formula down by creating named ranges for parts of the formula, using relative references and constants.

Here's an example:

[image]

Creating a named range for the SUBSTITUTE section with relative references and also for the text constant, it's possible to create a much shorter formula...:

[image]

... with the same result:

[image]

In your example, create a named range for `=IF(A2>2,CONCATENATE(.....))`, making sure you have the target cell selected when you create the named range, so that it is updated correctly when substituted into the long formula and filled down.

Comment: after just a few attempts this was the solution that worked. I had to split up the repetitive functions into 11 different defined names and 5 of them were nested substitutes. it seems indirect() references did not seem to work; but standard references do work even between multiple sheets (with some massaging) and all of this while still using a standard .xls. I know i didn't post my actual code because the whole point is it was too long, but it seems like you understood and I appreciate your point of view on this one and its what I needed to get past my coders-block. Thanks

Comment: it changed my formula from over 9000 to under 2500 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively create a Userdefined function to carry out the calculation and then the spreadsheet formula is purely the name of the udf plus the cell refs you want to use

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. These were all good ideas that I could not find in my searches. ForwardEd came real close with the CLEAN() function, thanks, but it did not clear the one I needed. And thanks teylyn for the tip on cleaning CONCATENATE(), but I only have 4 of those. I'm going to try a variation on Michael's solution, the SUBSTITUTE() is the bulkiest part and I see his use of Name Manager is not one I've seen before. (I didn't think that was the solution to my problem so I haven't focused on that.) I will be sure to post a result if anyone is interested.

SIDENOTE:
here is a copy of the character that I have not been able to identify but counts as a space and messes up my data every time, I had to add this to every reference that I have

```
SUBSTITUTE(D15,"​","")
```

Comment: No one can provide an exact solution because you didn't post an exact question. All we could provide was a solution approach and if my approach was able to meet your needs, you should mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: The character that is causing you problems in your data is the zero-width space. See: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space

Comment: Well you did ask a specific question: "are there any good options for a function that is too long, can't be shortened, and does not use vba?" And that's what was answered. Your function probably can be shortened but we can't help you shorten it without posting it. Even just telling us what types of characters you were trying to remove would have helped.